# spring acl in jsf

Tags: jsf, tomcat, spring-security, acl

i've just build in spring-security-acl into my system, how can i call the "hasPermission" el-function from my xhtml pages?

e.g.

```
<f:subview rendered="#{hasPermission(object,'read')}">
   HELLO
</f:subview>
```

i just get

```
javax.el.ELException: Function 'sec:hasPermission' not found
```

i'm running on tomcat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a taglib for the spring-security function.Then access the spring function with expression language like `#{prefix:function(params)}`

Refer the link [Spring Security Taglib and JSF](http://static.springsource.org/spring-webflow/docs/2.3.0.RELEASE/reference/html/ch13s11.html)

Comment: thanks, i'm using spring 3.1 is this manual still up-to-date?

Comment: seems that i need "spring-faces" for this, but i can only find a maven dependency for 2.3... any idea what to choose?

Comment: Yes, it's version is 2.3.1. It can be used with Spring-3.1